# Python: How to properly handle an exception using 'ask for forgiveness' (try–except) approach?

Tags: python, exception

I encountered a problem with my custom exceptions since they **exit the process (the interpreter displays a traceback) instead of being properly handled in the code**. Since I do not have much experience working with custom exceptions and exceptions imported from modules in the same code work properly, I pressue I made some mistake while defining my exceptions but I cannot find proper documentation to fix it myself.

Here is a sample code.

It is supposed to check whether XML path input by user works (by *work* I mean it returns the value contained within that XML element node) and if it does not work, it raises `XMLPrefixMissing` exception (due to possibly missing namespace prefix in the XML path). Then it uses an XML path with wildcard operator in place of a namespace prefix) but if it does not work anyways, it raises `XMLElementNotFound` (due to the fact that an element is possibly not in the XML file).

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

class Error(Exception):
    """Error base class"""
    pass

class XMLPrefixMissing(Error):
    """Error for when an element is not found on an XML path"""
    def __init__(self,
    message='No element found on an XML path. Possibly missing namespace prefix.'):
        self.message = message
        super(Error, self).__init__(message)

class XMLElementNotFound(Error):
    """Error for when an element value on an XML path is an empty string"""
    def __init__(self, message='No element found on an XML path.'):
        self.message = message
        super(Error, self).__init__(message)

# Some code

file = '.\folder\example_file.xml'
xml_path = './DataArea/Order/Item/Description/ItemName'
xml_path_with_wildcard = './{*}DataArea/{*}Order/{*}Item/{*}Description/{*}ItemName'
namespaces = {'': 'http://firstnamespace.example.com/', 'foo': 'http://secondnamespace.example.com/'}

def xml_parser(file, xml_path, xml_path_with_wildcard, namespaces):
    tree = ElementTree.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    try:
        if root.find(xml_path, namespaces=namespaces) is None:
            raise XMLElementNotFound
        # Some code
    except XMLPrefixMissing:
        if root.find(xml_path_with_wildcard, namespaces=namespaces) is None:
            raise XMLElementValueEmpty
        # Some code
    except XMLElementNotFound as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: what is the issue? what is the question? it is not clear from the post

Comment: If I'm not wrong, your problem is that the exceptions that you've made are not being raised but the ones in the `xml` module are? If so, yeah that's how it's supposed to work, what you should do is import the exceptions from the `xml` module and capture them, instead of capturing your own, since there is no way your exceptions will be raised from inside a module that does not have them defined anywhere.

Comment: @gold_cy Sorry for that, my current problem is that those custom exceptions exit the entire process instead of being handled by the code in an `except` block.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, try-except blocks kind of operate as an if/elif/else chain.

It looks to me like you're trying to raise exceptions in one except block in hopes that it will be caught in the next except block.

Instead, you should try to account for all exceptions inside the try block, and just have different except blocks to catch the different exceptions.

```
try:
    if root.find(xml_path, namespaces=namespaces) is None:
        raise XMLElementNotFound
    elif root.find(xml_path_with_wildcard, namespaces=namespaces) is None:
        raise XMLElementValueEmpty
except XMLPrefixMissing:
    #some code
except XMLElementValueEmpty as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: This has been very helpful and led me to rearange my code in better way. Thank you very much!